# How to get info on what scope is current

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

In Sublime hitting **Cmnd+R** keyboard shortcut brings a pull-down menu that allows to jump to a method/function definition by simply specifying its name:

[image]

But if there are two methods with the same name (declared under two different Classes) Sublime lists both same-name-methods without giving a clue to what Class a listed methods "belongs to".

What is the way around it?

---

```
class MyClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClassA, self).__init__()

    def method01(self):
        print 'MyClassA.method01'

    def method02(self):
        print 'MyClassA.method02'

    def method03(self):
        print 'MyClassA.method03'

    def method04(self):
        print 'MyClassA.method04'

    def method05(self):
        print 'MyClassA.method05'


class MyClassB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClassB, self).__init__()

    def method01(self):
        print 'MyClassB.method01'

    def method02(self):
        print 'MyClassB.method02'

    def method03(self):
        print 'MyClassB.method03'

    def method04(self):
        print 'MyClassB.method04'

    def method05(self):
        print 'MyClassB.method05'
```

Comment: You could put the classes in separate files

Comment: Outside the box, I know, but it's an option